# How to access parameters of parent function inside child function in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, function, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code to send mail .

```
public static function sendemail($recipient,$ticketdata)  
{
    Mail::send('emails.ticketbooked', $ticketdata, function ($message) {
        $message->to($recipient)->subject('Tickets Booking Confirmation');
    });
}
```

When this code is executed I am getting error message that "Undefined variable: recipient"

Kindly help me correct this error.

Comment: use [`use()`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) it'll be looked like `Mail::send('emails.ticketbooked', $ticketdata, function ($message) use($recipient) {...` if you want to access `$recipient` in the view you might need to pack `$ticketdata` and `$recipient` to an array, then pass it to `Mail::send(..)` parameters - just like how you put `$ticketdata`.

Comment: thanks brother it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tezla has pointed this out, but to bring in variables from a parent function when using `Mail` you need to utilise `use()`. It isn't mentioned in the docs, but it is used in the [example](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail) they provide:

```
public function sendEmail(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');

            $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
        });
    }
```

In the above example, they are finding the users details with an Eloquent query and then bringing those in to the `Mail` process with `use()`.

In your case, you would want to format it like so:

```
public static function sendemail($recipient,$ticketdata)  
{
    Mail::send('emails.ticketbooked', $ticketdata, function ($message) use($recipient) {
        $message->to($recipient)->subject('Tickets Booking Confirmation');
    });
}
```